# nav in header doesn't move next to an element that shrinks on page scroll

Tags: css, onscroll

I know very little to nothing of jQuery or JavaScript. So after fiddling - and failing - for hours here's my question:

In the header of my website (http://dev.shespeakswithpassionmembership.com/index.php), I have got an svg image that shrinks on scroll. Great, it works! 
But, what happens is: the menu doesn't jump next to the shrinking image. I want that because it saves a lot of space and it looks nicer. 
This is what I've done so far: 
The image is centered on load. For this I have added this CSS to the navbar-header:

```
.navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The image has got this CSS:

```
header.large img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    display: block;
}
```

When you scroll the image shrinks. As you can see the header has a class of **.large** and the image is shrunk by removing that class and replacing it with **.small**:

```
  header.small img {
    height: 49px;
    max-height: auto;
    width: 154px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 10px;
  }
```

This is done by this jQuery script:

```
function slabTextHeadlines(){jQuery("h1.slabbed").slabText({viewportBreakpoint:380,minCharsPerLine:10})}var App=function(){function e(){jQuery.browser.msie&&jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,1)<9&&jQuery("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").each(function(){var e=jQuery(this);jQuery(e).val(e.attr("placeholder")),jQuery(e).focus(function(){e.val()==e.attr("placeholder")&&e.val("")}),jQuery(e).blur(function(){(""==e.val()||e.val()==e.attr("placeholder"))&&e.val(e.attr("placeholder"))})})}function r(){jQuery(".carousel").carousel({interval:15e3,pause:"hover"}),jQuery(".tooltips").tooltip(),jQuery(".popovers").popover()}function o(){jQuery(".search").click(function(){jQuery(".search-btn").hasClass("icon-search")?(jQuery(".search-open").fadeIn(500),jQuery(".search-btn").removeClass("icon-search"),jQuery(".search-btn").addClass("icon-remove")):(jQuery(".search-open").fadeOut(500),jQuery(".search-btn").addClass("icon-search"),jQuery(".search-btn").removeClass("icon-remove"))})}return{init:function(){r(),e(),o()}}}();jQuery(document).on("scroll",function(){jQuery(document).scrollTop()>100?jQuery("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small"):jQuery("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large")}),jQuery(window).load(function(){setTimeout(slabTextHeadlines,.01)}),jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#totop").hide(),jQuery(window).scroll(function(){jQuery(this).scrollTop()>100?jQuery("#totop").fadeIn():jQuery("#totop").fadeOut()}),jQuery("#totop").click(function(){return jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},660,"easeInOutExpo"),!1})});
$(function() {
  $('[data-rspnsv]').rspnsv({delay: 200, duration: 3000});
});
```

For the menu to jump to the right of the svg image, I need to remove the **width: 100%;** and to assign a **width: auto;** to it. I would like to do that by adding a line of code to the script above so that it not only replaces **header.large** with **header.small**, but does the same trick with the navbar-header.

Is there anyone who can append the script to do this? To me it would seem rather simple for someone who knows about jQuery (which I don't).

Thanx in advance,

Thom

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS question. It doesn't require any jQuery changes. Add this CSS

```
header.small .navbar-header{
    width: auto;
}
```

If you want the menu to remain at the bottom, this is one way of doing that.

```
header.small #js-meganavi{
    margin-top: 46px;
}
```